# CPointer of CPointers in Kotlin/Native

Tags: kotlin-native

I would like to pass a variable to my C function with data type `char**`.

How do I pass such a variable with Kotlin/Native?

In other words, how do I initialize and use a nested CPointers in Kotlin/Native?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/c_interop.html#pointer-types), `char**` should be mapped to `CPointer<CPointerVar<ByteVar>>`. So, if you want to allocate a pointer like that, something like this should work:

```
memScoped {
    val charTwoStars = allocPointerTo<CPointerVar<ByteVar>>()
}
```

As I allocated this inside of the `memScoped` block, this variable will be accessible in the block, deallocated as soon as the block ends.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot. Is there a way to do it outside `memScoped{}`?

Comment: yes, you can [use nativeHeap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61161292/cpointer-of-cpointers-in-kotlin-native), but then you should manage memory yourself (call bnativeHeap.free manually)

Answer (score 0):

I found one way that works. However, it seems inelegant.

```
val tmp = "".cstr.getPointer(MemScope())
val a = listOf(tmp).toCValues().getPointer(MemScope())
```

Comment: This one is totally incorrect, as the memory will leak. The whole point of the `memScoped` block is to guarantee our memory allocations will be deallocated correctly. If you want to create something with a longer lifetime, please consider either a) allocate on the heap or b)allocate it on the Arena class instance. Both of those placements will require manual freeing at the end of the program. 
```
val myArena=Arena()
    val A = nativeHeap.allocPointerTo<CPointerVar<ByteVar>>()
    val B = myArena.allocPointerTo<CPointerVar<ByteVar>>()
    nativeHeap.free(A.rawPtr)
    myArena.clear()```